# Override BLAS with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, openblas

I usually switch between blas versions using `sudo update-alternatives ...`. However, I need to get it to work without sudo. I have tried several options, but none seem to work.

I have the following FORTRAN code to test if I have successfully switched libraries

```
      PROGRAM BLASTEST
         IMPLICIT NONE

         CALL MKL_Set_Num_Threads(1)
         CALL openblas_set_num_threads(1)

      END PROGRAM BLASTEST
```

I have intel MKL set as the preferred alternative, so when I compile using the following command, it results in an error that openblas_set_num_threads cannot be found.

`gfortran -o test test.f -lblas`

I have tried the following methods to get it to link with openblas instead, but it keeps linking with MKL:

- Create a symbolic link from ~/.local/alternatives/libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3 and add ~/.local/alternatives to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- Same method as before, but also add it to LIBRARY_PATH
- Compile using the following command `gfortran -o test test.f -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3 -lblas`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The common method is simply to set "the preferred" first in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when compiling : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [other command]`

Comment: That seems to do the trick on load time. I still can't get it to compile with openblas, but with your way, I at least get to use openblas at runtime which is sufficient for my use case. If you make an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Override BLAS with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Set `openblas` before "Intel MKL Blas" in the search path:

The common method is simply to set "the preferred" first in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when compiling :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [other command]
```